# Retrieve data from mysql using servlet as a webservice to android app

Tags: java, android, json, servlets

I want to retrieve the data which is stored in mysql database and i want to use servlet in between android app and mysql database.I wrote a code for saving data from android app to mysql database using httpPost. how can i do data retrieving?what should i refer? I dont want to use php

Comment: If you're implementing HTTP POST for writing, why not do something similar for reading?  Create another endpoint and use either POST or GET.

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: I'm confused.  You wrote the code to save data from the app to the database using a POST, but you don't know how to write the code to retrieve data using a GET?  The code is going to be very similar.  Can you explain more about where you're running into trouble?